# Problema ao mostrar imagem no imshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Tenho uma função que abre uma imagem e soma com uma matriz randômica mas a função `cv2.addWeighted` gera o seguinte erro mesmo com os tipos das duas matrizes sendo iguais :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Área de Trabalho/Pasta/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    Noise()
  File "/home/user/Área de Trabalho/Pasta/test.py", line 10, in Noise
    gaussian_noise = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,gaussian, 0.25, 0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:687: error: (-5:Bad argument) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op'
```

Então resolvi somar na mão mesmo( o que deu certo) mas na hora de mostrar, o resultado é tudo escuro, o que não condiz com a realidade. Segue o código :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
def Noise():

   img = cv2.imread('Imagen.jpg')
  # print(img)
   l,c,x=img.shape
   gaussian = np.int_(np.random.random((l, c, 3))*10)
   #gaussian_noise = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,gaussian, 0.25, 0)
   gaussian_noise=gaussian+img
   print(gaussian_noise)
   cv2.imshow("Original",img)
   cv2.imshow("Noise",gaussian_noise)
   cv2.waitKey(0)

Noise()
```

Alguém sabe por que o `cv2.imshow("Noise",gaussian_noise)` está aparecendo tudo escuro se a matriz tem valores corretos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua imagem `img` é do tipo `uint8`. O erro que está acontecendo é porque sua imagem `gaussian` não é do mesmo tipo que ela.

Para resolver isso, ao invés de criar a `gaussian` do tipo `int_`, você cria especificamente do tipo `uint8`:

```
gaussian = np.uint8(np.random.random((l, c, 3))*10)
```

Seu código vai ficar assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
def Noise():

   img = cv2.imread('Imagen.jpg')
   l,c,x=img.shape
   gaussian = np.uint8(np.random.random((l, c, 3))*10)
   gaussian_noise = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,gaussian, 0.25, 0)
   print(gaussian_noise)
   cv2.imshow("Original",img)
   cv2.imshow("Noise",gaussian_noise)
   cv2.waitKey(0)

Noise()
```

A forma manual que você usou para tentar resolver e alcançar o resultado não estava funcionando porque o `cv2.imshow()` espera valores entre 0 e 255 em cada posição da sua matriz. Acontece que ao somar o `img` com `gaussian`, os valores ultrapassaram o máximo de 255.

Comment: Eu vi que você multiplicou a matriz com valores aleatórios por 10 na variável gaussian. Você pode multiplicar ela até o limite de 255 se quiser gerar um ruído maior.

Comment: Ah, e como eu descobri que sua img é do tipo uint8? Eu testei pelo console chamando `img` e na última linha vem escrito o tipo `dtype=uint8`.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você está gerando os números aleatórios de forma errada, então a matriz `gaussian` não possui o mesmo data type do que a imagem. A maneira correta de gerar uma imagem aleatória colorida seria: `gaussian = np.round(np.random.rand(l, c, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)`

Como as duas imagens não possuem os mesmos data types, não é possível realizar a operação com o `cv2.addWeighted()`

Aparece a cor preta, pois o OpenCV exibe a imagem em BGR, que possui 3 canais de valores de 0 a 255. E do modo que você está somando, os valores estão passando de 255, gerando erros. Se você tentar mostrar a imagem após a soma, no matlplotlib, verá uma mensagem de erro, em que o matplotlib normaliza os valores de `gaussian_noise` automaticamente para valores entre 0 e 255 e depois é possível mostrar a imagem. Mas esta não é a maneira correta de realizar isso...

#### Código

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mostrar_imagem(img):
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()

def Noise():

   img = cv2.imread('Imagen.jpg')
  # print(img)
   l,c,x=img.shape
   gaussian = np.round(np.random.rand(l, c, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
   gaussian_noise = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.5,gaussian, 0.25, 0)
   # gaussian_noise=gaussian+img
   print(gaussian_noise)
   # mostrar_imagem(img)

   mostrar_imagem(gaussian_noise)
   
   #Ou Mostra a nova imagem e a original
   cv2.imshow("Original / Noise", np.hstack([img, gaussian_noise]))
   cv2.waitKey(0)


Noise()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Achei interessante o modo como gerou os números randômicos e principalmente o de mostrar as 2 imagens com np.hstack.